# dojo gridx wont read from JSONRest store - what am i missing here?

Tags: dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid, dojo

I having trouble populating a gridx widget from a JsonRest store. See my code below...
test1.json contains the same info as i have specified in the data for teststore.

When i change the grid to point at the teststore var it displays the contents correctly but when i point it at the reststore variable i get a 'No items to display' message.

Anyone know what im missing?

```
var restStore = new   dojo.store.JsonRest({target:"http://localhost:9081/MyProj/test1.json"});


var teststore = new Store({
 data: [
 {id: "1", "description":"First Description"},
 {id: "2", "description":"Second Description"},
 {id: "3", "description":"Third Description"},
 {id: "4", "description":"Fourth Description"}
       ]
});



  grid = new Grid({
    cacheClass: Cache,
    store: restStore,
    structure: [
      {id: "description", field: 'description', width: '100%'}
    ]
  }); 

grid.startup();
```

Comment: Have you tried with an actual service, or only with a static JSON endpoint?  That endpoint probably isn't going to set the Content-Range header as dojo/store/JsonRest expects, so that could be part of the problem...  see http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/quickstart/rest.html for more info.

Comment: Also note that you'll need to use `Async` cache (`gridx/core/model/cache/Async`).

Comment: its a static end point.... thanks for the link... is there any quicj way to set the content range header so i can see it working with the static json?...

Answer (score 0):

gridx and dojox.grid.DataGrid are *not* the same thing. dojox.grid.DataGrid is deprecated and only works with legacy dojo/data stores. You may use [`dojo/data/ObjectStore`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/data/ObjectStore.html) to wrap a dojo/store store with the dojo/data API:

```
var teststore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: new Store({ … }) });
```

However, if you are starting a new project, you should use [dgrid](http://dgrid.io) instead, which works natively with dojo/store stores.

Comment: hi there, im trying to do this with gridx control... just finding a good example is very hard...